# Randomize 2 lists for a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops

Lets say I have 2 lists of the same size along with the following code:

```
list1 = ['tom', 'mary', 'frank', 'joe']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for names, numbers in zip(list1, list2):
    print names, numbers
```

How would I use a random index from each list for each iteration of the for loop?

Along a similar note, if I have 2 lists of different sizes:

```
list1 = ['tom', 'mary', 'frank', 'joe', 'john', 'barry']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How do I, like the first example, use random indexes but this time, once it reaches the first index for the item that is outside list2, begin to randomize the index for list2 again for the remaining items in list1?  Is zip no longer the correct method to use in this case?

```
frank 3
tom 4
john 2
mary 1
barry 4
joe 2
```

^desired output (but completely random)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, to clarify, during each "cycle" of list1, I would like unique values for each "cycle"..

Comment: unique values from list2?

Comment: Yes, typo, list2, the shorter list *facepalm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works, but is kinda verbose:

```
import random

def shuffled(seq):
  copy = list(seq)
  random.shuffle(copy)
  return copy

def rand_repeat(seq):
  while True:
    for el in shuffled(seq):
      yield el

list1 = ['tom', 'mary', 'frank', 'joe', 'john', 'barry']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print zip(shuffled(list1), rand_repeat(list2))
```

Comment: won't that stop after 4 items ? don't you need to itertools.cycle at some point?

Comment: @njzk2: `rand_repeat()` does that using the `while` loop.

Comment: Right, I missed what the while True was there for.

Comment: Just don't use this with `izip_longest` (`rand_repeat` is never exhausted).

Comment: dumb question, but what if I don't know the length of each list or want python to be able to determine?

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = ['tom', 'mary', 'frank', 'joe', 'john', 'barry']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

random.shuffle(list2)
for name, number in zip(list1, itertools.cycle(list2)):
    print name, number
```

Comment: As per the question, 1. The first `len(list2)` values can be shuffled, and 2. the subsequent values occur only once without replacement, but "refilling" as necessary every `len(list2)` outputs.

Comment: Even after being shuffled, picks from list2 would still not be random -- given a long enough list1, the pattern would only repeat itself in a predictable fashion. list2 would have to be shuffled at the end of each cycle.

Comment: ... and even then, you'd have to have a way to ensure that the last element in list2 isn't the same as the first element in the next "cycle" of list2.

Answer (score 3):

I would loop until the first list is exhausted, randomly selecting items from list1 to and from list2:

```
while list1:
    for item in random.sample(list2, len(list2)):
        if not list1:
            break
        name = list1.pop(random.randrange(0, len(list1)))
        print name, item
```

Nota: `random.sample(list2, len(list2))` is a shuffling that returns a new list.

### Edit

Missed a break, result in a crash

Answer (score 1):

If you want to effectively iterate through some list in a random way, there are a lot of possible solutions, but I would suggest simply casting your `list` to a `set`, and then randomly sampling from the second list. You could do this like so:

```
for element in set(list1):
    print element, random.choice(list2)
```

If you want it to be truly random on different iterations, you could always use the `random.shuffle` function, but since that's well documented and referenced elsewhere, I thought you might like an answer with a different spin on things instead.

If you really want to implement the random sampling you described of your second element, I think I would just make your own class for it. Something like this:

```
class RandomList(object):
    def __init__(self, master_list):
        self.current_list = master_list
        self.master_list = master_list

    def __iter__(self):
        if not self.current_list:
            self.current_list = self.master_list
        index = random.choice(range(len(self.current_list)))
        value = self.current_list.pop(index)
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that you dont want to link list items index by index and make all by random but maybe that answer will be helpful to someone who want to zip two uneven length lists and fill empty space by random choosen values from smaller list.

---

Use [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) and [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
list1 = ['tom', 'mary', 'frank', 'joe', 'john', 'barry']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`izip_longest` just like `zip` makes tuples from two iterables but if the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with `None` (by default):

```
>>> list(izip_longest(list1, list2))
[('tom', 1), ('mary', 2), ('frank', 3), ('joe', 4), ('john', None), ('barry', None)]
```

Then you can check value for `None` in list comprehension and use `random.choice`:

```
>>> l = [(n, v if v else random.choice(list2)) for n,v in izip_longest(list1, list2)]
>>> l
[('tom', 1), ('mary', 2), ('frank', 3), ('joe', 4), ('john', 2), ('barry', 4)]
```

To randomize order of tuples you can use `random.shuffle`:

```
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[('mary', 2), ('john', 1), ('barry', 2), ('joe', 4), ('tom', 1), ('frank', 3)]
```

Comment: As per the question, 1. The first `len(list2)` values can be shuffled, and 2. the subsequent values occur only once without replacement, but "refilling" as necessary every `len(list2)` outputs.

Comment: after you exhaust list2, you are choosing from list2, but there can be repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most compact way is with [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random, itertools
>>> def randomizer(a, b):
...     prod = list(itertools.product(a, b))
...     while True:
...         yield random.choice(prod)
...
>>> r = randomizer('tom mary frank joe'.split(' '), range(1, 5))
>>> r.next()
('mary', 2)
>>> r.next()
('frank', 2)
>>> r.next()
('mary', 4)
>>> r.next()
('frank', 3)
>>> r.next()
('joe', 1)
```

You can unpack the tuple like this:

```
name, index = r.next()
```

Note that this will store an intermediate list of size `len(a) * len(b)` so it's not the most efficient from a space standpoint.

Comment: does not answer the question, because you can pick twice the same element from list1 before having exhausting it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
from collections import deque
from random import shuffle
from copy import copy

def make_deque(vals):
        back = copy(vals)
        shuffle(back)
        return deque(back)

prime = ['a','b','c','d','e']
support = [1,2,3,4]
deq = make_deque(support)
shuffle(prime)

for p in prime:
        try:
                s = deq.pop()
        except IndexError:
                deq = make_deque(support)
                s = deq.pop()
        print str(p) + " " + str(s)
```