# A function-like variable

Tags: python, function, variables, representation

[Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21613967/198633)]

Suppose I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['tom', 'mary', 'frank', 'joe', 'john', 'barry']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to match each name in `list1` with a number in `list2`. Since there are four numbers in `list2`, I would like to pair each of the first four names to the corresponding number in `list2`, and assign random numbers to the remaining names in `list1`.

I know that I can solve this problem using a for-loop with `enumerate` and `random.choice`. Indeed, I've provided [such a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614041/198633) to the original problem.
I would like to know however, if it is possible to do something like this:

```
for name, number in itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=MAGIC):
    print name, number
```

Originally, I thought of using something like this:

```
MAGIC = random.choice(list1)
```

However, that performs `random.choice(list1)` first, and then uses the answer as the `fillvalue` for the zipping operation. This is unattractive, as it does not choose a new random value for each pair of values that it zips. It is therefore clear, that `itertools.izip_longest` requires for its `fillvalue`, something that has a value by itself, which it doesn't call. Indeed, if I were to provide it a function, it would yield a pair consisting of a name, and a callable function, which is also undersired. For this reason, `lambda` functions are not feasible solutions.

How would I go about creating a variable that calls some function when it is called upon? How does `itertools.izip_longest` use the `fillvalue` variable? Is the `__repr__` of that variable called? If so, can I make a class with a `__repr__` that calls a function inside it?

Comment: "How would I go about creating a variable that calls some function when it is called upon?" - you wouldn't. You'd call a function.

Comment: You can get something like what you want for object attributes using properties, and in Python 3, you can get what you want at class scope using nasty metaclass magic, but for regular variables, you can't do it.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, but instances of a lot of classes show their `__repr__` values when "called upon"`. Thus, if `__repr__` was to call some external function, then all of a sudden, you have a variable, which holds an instance, whose value is determined by a function. Otherwise, I am indeed familiar with the difference between a variable and function.

Comment: `izip_longest` doesn't call `repr`. It just spits out the object directly.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: You really don't want `__repr__` to return a different value each time it's called. Besides, even if it did, the izip_longets approach still wouldn't work because the fillvalue is determined when you call the function, not each time it's filled in.

Comment: Suppose there were some magic value you could pass as `fillvalue` that would be one thing when you looked at it once and a different thing when you looked at it again. How would `izip_longest` know it should only look at this variable a certain number of times? What if it assumed the value would be the same every time, and some invariant in the C code driving `izip_longest` broke and caused a segfault?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems the simplest approach here would be to create a generator that yields all the filler values for eternity, then chain this with yielding the values in list2:

```
def inf_gen(f):
    while True:
        yield f()
```

Note that `inf_gen(f)` is actually equivalent to `iter(f, None)`, given that `f` never returns. `iter` with two arguments calls the first argument until it returns the second argument.

Then use it as such:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, chain
>>> for name, number in izip(list1,chain(list2, iter(lambda: random.choice(list2), None))):
    print name, number

tom 1
mary 2
frank 3
joe 4
john 1
barry 4
```

You can also do this just with itertools stuff without defining a separate function by using a generator comprehension with `itertools.count`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, chain, count
>>> for name, number in izip(list1, chain(list2, (random.choice(list2) for _ in count()))):
    print name, number
```

Comment: The two-argument form of `iter` is essentially what `inf_gen` is.

Comment: @chepner: oh nice! Totally forgot about iter. Will update answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to "scale" to multiple iterators, you could do it with a slight modification to the code given in http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=izip_longest#itertools.izip_longest :

```
from itertools import repeat, chain, count

class ZipExhausted(Exception):
    pass

def izip_longest2(*args, **kwds):
    fillvalue = kwds.get('fillvalue')
    fillgen = kwds.get('fillgen', repeat(fillvalue))  # added
    counter = [len(args) - 1]
    def sentinel():
        if not counter[0]:
            raise ZipExhausted
        counter[0] -= 1
        yield next(fillgen)  # modified
    iterators = [chain(it, sentinel(), fillgen) for it in args]  # modified
    try:
        while iterators:
            yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
    except ZipExhausted:
        pass


a = ['bob', 'mary', 'paul']
b = ['eggs', 'spam']
c = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for x in izip_longest2(a, b, c, fillgen=count()):
    print '\t'.join(map(str, x))

# output:
# bob   eggs    a
# mary  spam    b
# paul  0   c
# 1 2   d
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation?

Comment: EDIT: fixed indentation, thanks for pointing it out, @inspectorG4dget

Comment: This is actually quite brilliant! Thank you :)